# How to select the MAX from the COUNT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

[image]

That is a picture of my table.

I must select "Fastanumer" of all cars where "Tegund" is the most common value (which is Toyota in this example)

This is the code i tried

```
SELECT Fastanumer FROM  `Bill` 
WHERE Tegund =  
(SELECT MAX(y.cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(Tegund) AS cnt FROM Bill ) AS y)
```

Which i had to work pretty hard to figure out only to end up beating myself in the head over the fact that MAX will only turn into a number. (And since Tegund isn't a list of numbers...)

Is this even possible? How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it should work this way:

```
SELECT Fastanumer 
FROM  `Bill` 
WHERE Tegund = (
    SELECT Tegund 
    FROM (
        SELECT Tegund,COUNT(*) FROM Bill GROUP BY Tegund ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
    ) t1
)
```

Or even like this:

```
SELECT Fastanumer 
FROM  `Bill` 
WHERE Tegund = (
    SELECT Tegund FROM Bill GROUP BY Tegund ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
SELECT Bill.*
FROM Bill
WHERE Tegund IN (
  SELECT Tegund
  FROM Bill
  GROUP BY Tegund
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM Bill
      GROUP BY Tegund
    ) s
  )
)
```

A little more complicated than others, but if more than one `Tegund` shares the same number of rows, this query will show all Tegunds which are the most common.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64379/1) or [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64379/3).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do first is figure out which `Tegund` appears the most in your table. That is what the subquery is doing. Then you will select the `Fastanumer` which matches that `Tegund`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fastanumer 
FROM 'BILL'
WHERE Tegund = (
    SELECT TOPT 1 Tegund, 
                  COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM `BILL`
    GROUP BY Tegund
    ORDER BY Count DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the DB (and associated SQL). Try

```
select fastanumber from bill
    inner join
(select count(*) as cnt, tegund from Bill group by tegund) grpby
    on bill.tegund = grpby.tegund
    and grpby.cnt = (select max(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt, tegund from Bill group by tegund))
```